# Where is _vimperatorrc in windows?

Tags: vimperator

I've been using vimperator and I want to change how copy and paste works, but I don't know where _vimperatorrc is - any help?

Comment: You could use a search engine like Everything to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://osdir.com/ml/mozilla.firefox.vimperator/2007-08/msg00048.html) is a related message from mailing list. Shortly: you can place it in "C:\Documents and Settings\[user name]" for WinXP or "C:\Users\[user name]" for Vista and it should work. It is not created automatically so you'll probably need to create it by yourself. It is named exactly ".vimperatorrc": notice the starting dot and absence of file extension.

Comment: Actually you can't start files with a ., its an underscore.  Thanks for the help though, its much appreciated!

Comment: It is possible with tools like Far... which I'm using all the time

Comment: You can use the good ole cmd prompt to rename something so that it starts with a dot. Cumbersome, I know, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the vimperatorrc file should be created in `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/` in a modern Windows system.

- On Windows, Vimperator looks for `_vimperatorrc` first, then `.vimperatorrc`.
- Windows explorer refuses to name files beginning with a dot, but it will handle them fine. You can create such file names with other tools such as the command line, Vim, Emacs, alternative file managers or Vimperator itself.
- If you don't already have an rc file, you can use the `mkvimperatorrc` command to create one with your current bindings and commands.

  - ```
    mkvimperatorrc
    ```

    Creates `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/_vimperatorrc` on Windows (or `~/.vimperatorrc` on Unix)
  - ```
    mkvimperatorrc ~/.vimperatorrc
    ```

    Creates `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/.vimperatorrc` on Windows.